# Mongoose cursor eachAsync creates memory leak

Tags: node.js, mongoose, memory-leaks, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I want to iterate 1000 docs with Mongoose cursor.eachAsync with batch size 10. Sometimes it creates a memory leak. each iteration of data will be sent to an AWS SQS queue for further proceedings.

```
    let campaignUserCursor = await this.campaignUserModel
    .aggregate([...query])
    .allowDiskUse(true)
    .cursor({ batchSize: 10 })
    .exec();
  campaignUserCursor.eachAsync(async (campaignUser) => {
        const queueObj = this.setObj(campaignUser);
        await this.sqsProducerService.sendMessage(queueObj);
        await this.broadcastRepository.updateBroadcast(queueObj, {
        $inc: { total_queue_count: 1 }});
     },
     { parallel: 10 },() => {});
```

memory leak will happens occasionally if the number of doc size is more. Is there any way to handle Mongoose iteration without a memory leak?

Also, how can we send batch messages to SQS with @ssut/nestjs-sqs module? The primary goal is to send these Mongoose docs to Queue for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what may be causing the memory leak, you will need to analyze and monitor the memory by starting your application with `node --inspect` and in conjunction with your browser's DevTools `chrome://inspect`, when accessing this url will have a `Devices` section you can configure which address will be monitored, for example `127.0.0.1:3000`, clicking on the `inspect` button, opens the `Menory` section through it you can give you a direction of what it actually is is causing the memory leak.

One of the problems I've had with memory leaks was when I was developing a file upload system, using `inspect` I discovered that one of the problems was that when scrolling through an array, a connection to mongoose was being opened. for each item that I was updating in the database, for me it was necessary to close the connection.

Maybe `node --inspect` can help you, for me looking at the Node.js documentation this was what really helped me solve the memory leak problem in my application.